# jQuery select next <div> element

Tags: jquery

I have a simple div layout html, there is a function that when mouse over the div with className "personal-icon-email", I will call a JS function and display the hidden div with className "img-info-mask".

```
<div class="user-panel">
<div class="user-panel-avatar"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50?s=80"/></div>
<div class="user-panel-username">Frank</div>
<div class="user-panel-info">Hi there, May name is Frank ....</div> 
<div class="personal-icon-email pie-adj" onmouseover="showTips(this);" id="123321"></div>
<div class="personal-icon-hi pihi-adj"></div>
<div class="personal-icon-fav pifav-adj"></div>
<div class="img-info-mask">Contact Frank Now</div>
```

I was using jQuery with this and I have tried:

```
function showTips(object){$(object).next('.img-info-masks').show(); }
```

But failed. 
Also i have tried

`function showTips(object){$('#123321').next('.img-info-masks').show();}`

Still not works.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong and what i should do? Thank you a thousand :D

Comment: Firstly, it is img-info-mask not img-info-masks. Is the div you want to show the only occurrence of a div with that class name on the page? If so, you could just do $('.img-info-mask').show();

Comment: Also note it is invalid HTML to use values for id attributes that are all numbers, e.g. 123321, and that can cause problems with JavaScript at times.

Comment: You're already using jQuery... time to step up your event binding and use `.on()` instead of the inline onmouseover (assuming jQuery 1.7+, otherwise `.bind()` (incl. bind aliases) or `.delegate()`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also use [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) instead of [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and than find your `img-info-mask`

want to show all the `div.img-info-mask` than try

```
$(object).nextAll('div.img-info-mask').show();
```

or want to first `div` with contains `.img-info-mask`

```
$(object).nextAll('div.img-info-mask:first').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.personal-icon-email").mouseover(function(){
     $("div.img-info-mask").show();
});
```

You need to select the item you want to monitor for the mouseover event and then add the event handler for mouseover.  In that function, you show the hidden div.  You can also show it, then hide it when the mouse leaves by using the hover() event handler like this:

```
$("div.personal-icon-email").hover(function(){
    //mouseover event
    $("div.img-info-mask").show();
},
function(){
    //mouseout event
    $("div.img-info-mask").hide();
});
```

Or you can make it even simpler:

```
$("div.personal-icon-email").hover(function(){
    //mouseover and mouseout event
    $("div.img-info-mask").toggle();
});
```

This calls the one function for both mouseover and mouseout, toggling the visibility each time.

So now you want to do this for just the next occurrence of the hidden info?  Ok, that can be done too.

```
$("div.personal-icon-email").hover(function(){
    //mouseover and mouseout event
    $(this).parent().find('div.img-info-mask').toggle();
});
```

That will target the next sibiling div with the .img-info-mask class.  You'll to make sure that each set of div's like the sample you gave is inside a parent div, or you'll be toggling all of the hidden divs at once.

Comment: Thanks, the problems i have about 100 div with the same class name and i only want to display the closet div with that className.

Comment: Ohhhhh, your question didn't make that clear.  It's still doable.

Comment: @SurrealDreams I didn't know about nextUntil... so used to using `closest` or `parent` and then `find`. Cheers!

Comment: Had to fiddle with it a bit - $(this).nextUntil() doesn't work, but $(this).parent().find() does.  Credit to Andreas for that.

Answer (score 1):

`next()` only retrieves the immediate next sibling, it doesn't actually traverse all siblings.

http://api.jquery.com/next/

```
Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of 
matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next 
sibling only if it matches that selector.
```

For one, if you wrap those divs in a parent div, you could do

```
$(this).parent().find('.img-info-mask').show()
```

Comment: Wow...Thans you very much.... I spent a whole morning and you just woke me up in 5 seconds. Thank you co much :DD

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
$(".personal-icon-email").hover(function() {
  $(".img-info-mask").show();
},
function() {
  $(".img-info-mask").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery next: Gets the IMMEDIATELY following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

.img-info-masks is not immediately following the selected element.