# How to select next div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this part many times in a page:

```
<a class="showComment" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="icon-comment"></i> Views</a>
<br />
<br />
<div class="writeComment" style="height: auto; width: 700px;" dir="ltr" hidden="hidden">
</div>
```

I am now writing code in a js file for `a.showComment` click event.Now I want to select next `div.writeComment`.How to select it?

Comment: define 'select' it? like, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629213/jquery-select-next-div-element?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

next() didnt work.

nextAll() was for all of .writeComment elements that were after my .showComment element.But I found the issue.The following code made it.

```
$('.showComment').click(function(){
     $(this).nextAll(".writeComment").first();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In the variable nextDiv you can do whatever you want
Using `.nextAll()` method allows us to search through the successors of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

using `.next()` instead you search after the DOM element that you have clicked
try this:

```
 $('.showComment').click(function(){
        var nextDiv = $(this).nextAll("div.writeComment");
    });
```

Or

```
$('.showComment').click(function(){
            var nextDiv =  $('.showComment').next().find('.writeComment')
        });
```

Or

```
$('.showComment').click(function(){
        var nextDiv = $(this).next("div.writeComment");
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

This might show you to the right way using next() http://api.jquery.com/next/
The selector will be as following:

so:

```
$('.showComment').next('.writeComment')
```

or:

```
$('.showComment').next().find('.writeComment')
```

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Thank you for improving :) much appreciated cheers!

Comment: no worries, i didn't do much haha. the misspelling was the only real issue, i just hate seeing tag qualifiers on selectors because its unnecessary and only serves to make it less efficient.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you use jQuery. Otherwise, I strongly encourage you to do so.
It has a [next-statement](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$('#foo').next().css('background-color', 'red');
```

sets the element after foo th background:red.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `~` selector. [JQuery Reference](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/)

```
$('a.showComment ~ div.writeComment')
```